# Drupal 8 views-view-field.html.twig

Tags: twig, drupal-8

this is going to be quick and direct. I'm trying to access different content results from a view related with a content type. I'm pretty much a newbie with twig, but I did make it work to access fields.

Example:

```
 Content Type: Books
 Fields: Name, Portrait(Image). Machine Name: field_name - field_image
```

Let's say I upload 2 contents called Book 1 and Book 2 based on the content type.

What I want is to display all fields from Book 1 for the moment or Book 2 but not all of the content at the same time.

My effort:

- First attempt: tried this line of code

  `<h2>{{view.field.field_name.getvalue(view.result[0])}}</h2>`

  Works perfectly, it prints index 0 but not working printing the image, because instead it gives me the id.
- Second attempt: tried this line of code:

  `{{fields.field_image.content}}`

  This one seems to be the most practical, it works showing the actual picture from the field image, but I dont know how to access only the image for one index(Book 1).
- Third attempt: tried this line of code

  `{{content.field_image.0}}`

  This one doesnt work for me at all.

Hopefully somebody would help me with this. I've been struggling one week with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on Twig debugging, then do a dump to see how things are structured.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/discovering-and-inspecting-variables-in-twig-templates

Or perhaps look at the Twig Tweak module that gives a lot of great functions that might suite your needs:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet-8x-2x

This one in particular might be good since you have the ID in your first example:

```
{# The argument can be FID, UUID or URI. #}
  <dt>Image:</dt>
  <dd>{{ drupal_image('public://ocean.jpg') }}</dd>
```